# p5.js keyIsDown() behaving inconsistently when more than 2 keys are pressed at once

Tags: javascript, p5.js

My code (reduced to demonstrate bug) consists of a keyboard class which handles drawing keys in specific locations and sets their color based on some logic and a key class which handles drawing the key and keeping track of other attributes.

```js
class key {
    constructor (w, h, code, color) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.code = code;
        this.color = color;
        this.isDown = false;
    }
    
    draw(x, y) {
        strokeWeight(2);
        stroke("#c8c8c8");
        fill(this.color);
        rect(x, y, this.w, this.h, 7);
    }
    
    update() {
        this.isDown = keyIsDown(this.code);
    }
}

class Keyboard {
    constructor(keySize) {
        this.keySize = keySize;
        this.keycodes = [81, 87, 69, 82, 84, 89, 85, 73, 79, 80, 65, 83, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 90, 88, 67, 86, 66, 78, 77, 32, 18];
        
        this.altWidth = keySize * 1.3;
        this.spaceWidth = keySize * 7;
        
        this.keys = new Array(28);
        for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            this.keys[i] = new key(keySize, keySize, this.keycodes[i], "#505050");
        }
        this.keys[26] = new key(this.spaceWidth, this.keySize, this.keycodes[26], "#505050");
        this.keys[27] = new key(this.altWidth, this.keySize, this.keycodes[27], "#505050");
    }
    
    draw(x, y) {
        let rowOffsets = [0, 2 * this.keySize / 7, this.keySize, this.keySize * 1.6];
        
        /* draws row 1 of letter keys */
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.keys[i].draw(x + rowOffsets[0] + i * (this.keySize + this.keySize / 7), y);
        }
        /* draws row 2 of letter keys */
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            this.keys[i + 10].draw(x + rowOffsets[1] + i * (this.keySize + this.keySize / 7), y + this.keySize + this.keySize / 7);
        }
        /* draws row 3 of letter keys */
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            this.keys[i + 19].draw(x + rowOffsets[2] + i * (this.keySize + this.keySize / 7), y + 2 * (this.keySize + this.keySize / 7));
        }
        
        /* draws space bar */
        this.keys[26].draw(x + rowOffsets[3] + this.altWidth + this.keySize / 7, y + 3 * (this.keySize + this.keySize / 7));
        
        /* draws left alt */
        this.keys[27].draw(x + rowOffsets[3], y + 3 * (this.keySize + this.keySize / 7));
    }
    
    update() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            this.keys[i].update();
            if (this.keys[i].isDown) {
                this.keys[i].color = "#a05050";
            } else {
                this.keys[i].color = "#505050";
            }
        }
    }
}


let canvasWidth = 720;
let canvasHeight = 480;
let keySize = 50;
let k = new Keyboard(keySize);

function setup() {
    frameRate(60);
    createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}

function draw() {
    background("#302030");
    k.update();
    k.draw(50, 50);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

In this case the logic is simple so it seems tempting to simply delegate it to the key class, but in my actual project it is more complicated and it made the most sense to have the keys and the keyboard communicate in this way. When the code snippet is run, the expected behavior is that a key changes color when pressed down, independently of the number of keys being held.

This appears to work perfectly for 2 keys, however, if more than 2 keys are held, the behavior is buggy and inconsistent with additional keys being held liable to change color or not. Is this a potential bug with p5.js, or am I overlooking something?

If it is a bug, any suggestions on alternative strategies to achieve the desired behavior would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this behavior is a keyboard limitation, it has a limit on how many keys a keyboard can recognize.
I tested it on [another site](https://en.key-test.ru/) that has the same purpose and the behavior is the same.

My keyboard can recognize more than 5 keys.

Furthermore, I think there is no way to make this work.

[How do I remove the limit on PC keyboard button presses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses)

Comment: Having tested it on another keyboard, I think this is likely. Makes me feel better about the behavior because if questioned, it asn't on me haha. Thanks for the response!