# How do I make an image stay on the screen after pressing a key with p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm having a bit of trouble with my p5.js project. As of right now, every time I press the up arrow my images appear on the screen, but only for a second. Is there a way to have them stay on the screen after pressing the up arrow? I want to be able to have a different set of images pop up in the same location every time I press a different arrow key, and have the last set of images disappear.

```js
function preload() {
  img1 = loadImage("img/Q.png");
  img2 = loadImage("img/W.png");
  img3 = loadImage("img/E.png");
  img4 = loadImage("img/R.png");
  img5 = loadImage("img/T.png");
  img6 = loadImage("img/Y.png");
  song1 = loadSound("audio/1.wav");
  song2 = loadSound("audio/2.wav");
  song3 = loadSound("audio/3.wav");
  song4 = loadSound("audio/4.wav");
  song5 = loadSound("audio/5.wav");
  song6 = loadSound("audio/6.wav");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024, 764);
  h = 0;
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
}

function keyTyped() {
  typed += key;
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    image(img1, 20, 650, 100, 100);
    image(img2, 200, 650, 100, 100);
    image(img3, 380, 650, 100, 100);
    image(img4, 560, 650, 100, 100);
    image(img5, 740, 650, 100, 100);
    image(img6, 910, 650, 100, 100);

    if (key == 'q' || key == 'Q') {
      image(img1, 20, 550, 100, 100);
    }
    if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
      image(img2, 200, 550, 100, 100);
    }
    if (key == 'e' || key == 'E') {
      image(img3, 380, 550, 100, 100);
    }
    if (key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
      image(img4, 560, 550, 100, 100);
    }
    if (key == 't' || key == 'T') {
      image(img5, 740, 550, 100, 100);
    }
    if (key == 'y' || key == 'Y') {
      image(img6, 910, 550, 100, 100);
    }
  }
  if (key == '2') {
    image(img1, 20, 650, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Save the last pressed key into a variable and move the drawing into the `draw` function, or move the `background(0)` call, which overwrites the canvas, from `draw` to `keyPressed`.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks! Is there a way to only have the arrow keys override one another. For example if I press the up arrow key, my images will show up, but if I then code an animation for the 'q' key, the images go away. Is it possible to have them stay on the screen until I press a different arrow key, while simultaneously being able to press letters that trigger animations?

Comment: Yep, probably moving it to the `draw` function. Can you share your latest code please? BTW, check out arrays and loops instead of `thing1`, `thing2`, etc

Comment: Thank you, I just updated the code in the original post.

Comment: See [Detect multiple keypresses and trigger an action once in p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72881145/detect-multiple-keypresses-and-trigger-an-action-once-in-p5-js) for handling multiple keys. Since your edit makes the post no longer match the title, I'm rolling back to the original code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the image disappears is because the `draw()` function is called roughly 60 times a second to support animations. The content of your `draw()` is the typical `background(0)` which wipes the screen. Generally, the next step  in `draw()` after clearing the background is to re-draw the objects that should appear on the screen.

Now, a `keyPressed` handler fires only once when a key is pressed, so if it renders an image, you'll see that image for at most a split second before it's wiped out by the `background(0)` which runs a moment later in `draw()`:

```
     keyPressed()/image()
            |
            V
... draw() -> draw() -> draw() -> draw() -> ...
      |         |         |         |
      |         v         v         |
      +-------->background(0)<------+ // erases everything

time -->
```

There are a few approaches for handling this situation:

1. Move the drawing code to `draw()` and check `keyCode`/`key` in the main loop instead of in the `keyPressed` handler. This gives you the opportunity to draw *after* each `background(0)` call. The disadvantage of testing `keyCode`/`key` directly in `draw()` is that it won't work for multiple keys since `key` and `keyCode` can only hold a single value at a time.
2. Call `noLoop()` in `setup()` to cause `draw()` to trigger only once, so that `background(0)` isn't spamming the console. For animation-driven apps, this is probably the wrong approach, but it can be useful for event-driven, non-animating situations. For example, in this case, you could use `keyReleased()` to trigger another call to `background(0)` to wipe the screen. It's possible to use `loop()` and `noLoop(0)` to strategically enable and disable the event loop.
3. Combine #1 from above with a [multi-keypress handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72885871/6243352) that keeps track of all of the keys pressed by the user at once, then make decisions in the `draw()` function
   about what to show on each frame based on the currently-pressed keys.

In this particular case, since you want to process multiple keys, the multi-key handler is basically required for all implementations, but I'll start without it to keep it simple.

Here are some generic examples you can adapt. Note that I'm using objects and arrays rather than `img1`, `img2`, ... and `if`s, and I've adjusted the coordinates to make it easier to see in the stack snippet. Keys are QWERTY throughout.

##### Example 1 (key detection in `draw()`, one key at a time):

```js
const keyMapping =  {
  q: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/40",
    coords: [0, 0, 40, 40],
  },
  w: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/60",
    coords: [40, 0, 40, 60],
  },
  e: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/80",
    coords: [80, 0, 40, 80],
  },
  r: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/100",
    coords: [120, 0, 40, 100],
  },
  t: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/120",
    coords: [160, 0, 40, 120],
  },
  y: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/140",
    coords: [200, 0, 40, 140],
  },
};

function preload() {
  for (const k in keyMapping) {
    keyMapping[k].image = loadImage(keyMapping[k].url);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(240, 140);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  const toDraw = keyMapping[key];
  
  if (toDraw) {
    image(toDraw.image, ...toDraw.coords);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Since `key` holds whatever key was last pressed, this persists the image associated with the latest key even after it's been released.

##### Example 2 (`noLoop()` with only `keyPressed`):

```js
const keyMapping =  {
  q: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/40",
    coords: [0, 0, 40, 40],
  },
  w: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/60",
    coords: [40, 0, 40, 60],
  },
  e: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/80",
    coords: [80, 0, 40, 80],
  },
  r: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/100",
    coords: [120, 0, 40, 100],
  },
  t: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/120",
    coords: [160, 0, 40, 120],
  },
  y: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/140",
    coords: [200, 0, 40, 140],
  },
};

function preload() {
  for (const k in keyMapping) {
    keyMapping[k].image = loadImage(keyMapping[k].url);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(240, 140);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
}

function keyPressed() {
  const toDraw = keyMapping[key];
  
  if (toDraw) {
    background(0); // optionally remove to persist all drawn images
    image(toDraw.image, ...toDraw.coords);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

##### Example 3 (`noLoop()` with `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`):

```js
const keyMapping =  {
  q: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/40",
    coords: [0, 0, 40, 40],
  },
  w: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/60",
    coords: [40, 0, 40, 60],
  },
  e: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/80",
    coords: [80, 0, 40, 80],
  },
  r: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/100",
    coords: [120, 0, 40, 100],
  },
  t: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/120",
    coords: [160, 0, 40, 120],
  },
  y: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/140",
    coords: [200, 0, 40, 140],
  },
};

function preload() {
  for (const k in keyMapping) {
    keyMapping[k].image = loadImage(keyMapping[k].url);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(240, 140);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
}

function keyPressed() {
  const toDraw = keyMapping[key];
  
  if (toDraw) {
    image(toDraw.image, ...toDraw.coords);
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (!keyIsPressed) { // optional
    background(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Note that the [operating system may limit how many keys can be pressed at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72253282/p5-js-keyisdown-behaving-inconsistently-when-more-than-2-keys-are-pressed-at-o).

##### Example 4 (`noLoop()` with `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` and a set of pressed keys):

```js
const pressed = new Set();
const keyMapping =  {
  q: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/40",
    coords: [0, 0, 40, 40],
  },
  w: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/60",
    coords: [40, 0, 40, 60],
  },
  e: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/80",
    coords: [80, 0, 40, 80],
  },
  r: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/100",
    coords: [120, 0, 40, 100],
  },
  t: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/120",
    coords: [160, 0, 40, 120],
  },
  y: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/140",
    coords: [200, 0, 40, 140],
  },
};

function preload() {
  for (const k in keyMapping) {
    keyMapping[k].image = loadImage(keyMapping[k].url);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(240, 140);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
}

function keyPressed() {
  pressed.add(key);
  showImage(key);
}

function keyReleased() {
  pressed.delete(key);
  background(0);

  // optionally redraw images for keys still pressed
  for (const k of [...pressed]) {
    showImage(k);
  }
}

function showImage(k) {
  const toDraw = keyMapping[k];

  if (toDraw) {
    image(toDraw.image, ...toDraw.coords);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

##### Example 5 (`draw()` with `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` and a set of pressed keys):

```js
const pressed = new Set();
const keyMapping =  {
  q: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/40",
    coords: [0, 0, 40, 40],
  },
  w: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/60",
    coords: [40, 0, 40, 60],
  },
  e: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/80",
    coords: [80, 0, 40, 80],
  },
  r: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/100",
    coords: [120, 0, 40, 100],
  },
  t: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/120",
    coords: [160, 0, 40, 120],
  },
  y: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/140",
    coords: [200, 0, 40, 140],
  },
};

function preload() {
  for (const k in keyMapping) {
    keyMapping[k].image = loadImage(keyMapping[k].url);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(240, 140);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  
  for (const k of [...pressed]) {
    showImage(k);
  }
}

function keyPressed() {
  pressed.add(key);
}

function keyReleased() {
  pressed.delete(key);
}

function showImage(k) {
  const toDraw = keyMapping[k];

  if (toDraw) {
    image(toDraw.image, ...toDraw.coords);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

##### Example 6 (`draw()` with `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` and a set of pressed keys, plus requiring the up arrow to be held to activate the QWERTY keys):

```js
const pressed = new Set();
const keyMapping =  {
  q: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/40",
    coords: [0, 0, 40, 40],
  },
  w: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/60",
    coords: [40, 0, 40, 60],
  },
  e: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/80",
    coords: [80, 0, 40, 80],
  },
  r: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/100",
    coords: [120, 0, 40, 100],
  },
  t: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/120",
    coords: [160, 0, 40, 120],
  },
  y: {
    url: "https://picsum.photos/40/140",
    coords: [200, 0, 40, 140],
  },
};

function preload() {
  for (const k in keyMapping) {
    keyMapping[k].image = loadImage(keyMapping[k].url);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(240, 140);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  
  for (const k of [...pressed]) {
    showImage(k);
  }
}

function keyPressed(e) {
  if (e.code.startsWith("Arrow")) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  pressed.add(key);
}

function keyReleased() {
  pressed.delete(key);
}

function showImage(k) {
  const toDraw = keyMapping[k];

  if (toDraw && pressed.has("ArrowUp")) {
    image(toDraw.image, ...toDraw.coords);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

The only modification here is a condition to ensure the user is holding down the arrow key before drawing anything, hopefully fulfilling OP's original intent.

```js
//         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
if (toDraw && pressed.has("ArrowUp")) {
  image(toDraw.image, ...toDraw.coords);
}
```